# Why does position of my picture change in PDF output with same code?

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, knitr

I have a block of code where I am just trying to left justify a few headings and right justify a picture:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{letterpaper, top=0.45in, bottom=0.5in, left=0.5in, right=0.5in}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
\LARGE Conservation Action Mapping \\
\normalsize Pennsylvania State Wildlife Action Plan \\
Project name: \\
Date: 
\end{minipage}%

\hfill

\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}\raggedleft
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{logo}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

For a while, this code was having the desired effect with the picture in the top right and the text in the top left.  However, I tried running it through an R script with knitr and it started putting the picture on a new line like this:

[image]

When I changed the code back to what I had before (and what is shown above), it still produces the PDF with the picture on the new line.

Comment: you have a paragraph break between the minipages so naturally they come one above the other,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The empty lines you leave before and after `\hfill` each are instructions to start a new paragraph which is consequently set in a new line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{letterpaper, top=0.45in, bottom=0.5in, left=0.5in, right=0.5in}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
    {\LARGE Conservation Action Mapping}

    Pennsylvania State Wildlife Action Plan 

    Project name: 

    Date: 
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you!  This seems obvious, but I'm new to latex and didn't know spaces signified paragraph breaks.  This is very helpful.  Thanks again!